# Rezorpay integration using showing error in CMD(Firebase cloud function)

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using the firebase cloud function to create order id for Razorpay for my Android app using 'call' function as shown below. But I am unable to upload the code-

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const Razorpay = require('razorpay')
const instance = new Razorpay({ key_id: 'myKey', key_secret: 'mySecretKey' })
 
exports.createOrder = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

   var options = {
     amount: 50000,  // amount in paisa
     currency: "INR",
     receipt: "order_rcptid_11"
   }; 
   
    try{
        const order = await instance.orders.create(options);
        res.send(order);
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        res.status(403).send({error: 'error'});
    }
    
});
```

The error is -

```
      error  Parsing error: Unexpected token instance
events.js:200
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
```

Here 22 means the following line

```
 const order = await instance.orders.create(options);
```

What is wrong with it? I don't know much about JS and NODE Js.

Package.json file inside function folder

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Package.json file outside function folder

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "razorpay": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

Complete error message

```
 22:29  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token instance

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

events.js:200
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\Bhaskar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\Bhaskar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Bhaskar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Bhaskar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
  path: 'npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
  spawnargs: []
}

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

Here 22 means the following line

```
 const order = await instance.orders.create(options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related with `await`. Not sure why its not so clear in the error however, `await` can be used inside asynchronous function ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)). So we have 3 options to correct (probably more, but giving 3 here):

1. make function asynchronous adding the `async` keyword like this:

```
...
exports.createOrder = functions.https.onCall( async (data, context)=> {
...
```

2. Use `then` instead of `await` in `try`:

```
...
try{
        instance.orders.create(options).then(order => res.send(order));
    }catch(e){
...
```

3. Use callback function like in [example](https://razorpay.com/docs/api/orders/) on Razorpay.

I tested first 2 on my side and they are deploying correctly. I don't know if this is working correctly as this is first time I see Razorpay. However it deploys with no error.